# Unexplained change in data in request/response

Tags: javascript, telerik, xmlhttprequest, openedge

I am having a very strange problem and I really hope you all can tell my how I'm being dumb and why this is happening.

I have a mobile app that I'm building using the Telerik Appbuilder. The back end is all written on OpenEdge 11.6 and I'm using the Pacific App Server for OE to serve everything up. I am also using the JSDO to interact with my data on the client side.

For some reason when I call jsdo.assign() and send over and object of data to update, all the field get updated except one. It is the only field that is defined as a decimal data type. It looks like the data is being sent as decimal, but somewhere along the line something changes and looks like it gets turned into an integer, or at the very least something OpenEdge does not like.

My request payload looks like this (TEMP is the offending field):

[image: Request]

My response looks like this:

[image: Response]

What is happening? What could be meddling with my data? I really don't know where to start.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your request and response screenshots are the same

Comment: Sorry about that, it is now fixed. Although they still do look almost exactly the same. Request shows TEMP as 15.1 and Response shows 15.

Comment: It seems to me something in the back end is rounding the number. Is there any chance you could expose what´s being done to temp in the back end (if anything?)
Check the input (and output) parameters. If you pass a decimal to an integer parameter in Progress, you don´t get any error, it´s implicitly converted. Or some function could be rounding/forcing it to round down to zero decimals. Just off the top of my head. As I said, I´d like to see the methods and parameters and calculations involving TEMP to be sure.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the issue once I knew where to look. In the Temp-Table definition, the fields were not defined in the correct order. Specifically, the TEMP field was defined third when in the table it is the last field, if that makes sense. I moved the definition to correspond with its location in the table and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my temp-table definition, as it did not reflect the structure of the table. Originally, my code looked like this:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttWHS_TEMP_REPORT BEFORE-TABLE bttWHS_TEMP_REPORT
FIELD LOCATION_ID AS INTEGER INITIAL "0" LABEL "Location_Id"
FIELD LOCATION_NAME AS CHARACTER LABEL "Location_Name"
FIELD TEMP AS DECIMAL INITIAL "0" LABEL "Temp"
FIELD IN_RANGE AS LOGICAL INITIAL "no" LABEL "In_Range"
FIELD EMPLOYEE AS CHARACTER LABEL "Employee"
FIELD STAMP_DT AS DATE INITIAL "?" LABEL "Stamp_DT"
FIELD STAMP_TM AS CHARACTER LABEL "Stamp_TM"
FIELD REPORT_ID AS INTEGER INITIAL "0" LABEL "?".
```

I simply changed it to look like this:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttWHS_TEMP_REPORT BEFORE-TABLE bttWHS_TEMP_REPORT
FIELD LOCATION_ID AS INTEGER INITIAL "0" LABEL "Location_Id"
FIELD LOCATION_NAME AS CHARACTER LABEL "Location_Name"
FIELD IN_RANGE AS LOGICAL INITIAL "no" LABEL "In_Range"
FIELD EMPLOYEE AS CHARACTER LABEL "Employee"
FIELD STAMP_DT AS DATE INITIAL "?" LABEL "Stamp_DT"
FIELD STAMP_TM AS CHARACTER LABEL "Stamp_TM"
FIELD REPORT_ID AS INTEGER INITIAL "0" LABEL "?"
FIELD TEMP AS DECIMAL INITIAL "0" LABEL "Temp".
```

I had made changes to  my table after defining the temp-table, and I did not know enough about OpenEdge to realize that the order of fields defined in the temp table mattered.

Comment: Happy to hear you fixed it. In the future, as good practice, turn the temp-table definition into an include and instantiate it in both back and front ends. This way, you ensure the signatures always match.